# Global variable in a different library, C

Tags: c

I am trying a global variable to hold my error message in C.

One library called Utils has:

```
#ifndef private_error_h
#define private_error_h

extern char error[1024];

__declspec(dllexport) void FillError(char* newError);
#define GetErr() error

#endif
```

File error.c:

```
#include "private_error.h"

char error[1024];
void FillError(char* newError) {
  // ...
}
```

Then I try to use it in a program:

```
#include "private_error.h"

int main() {
  FillError("General error");
  printf("%s\n", GetErr());
  return 0;
}
```

It creates two variables with different addresses.  How can I make the program use the variable from the Utils library?

I did manage to bypass this problem by changing GetErr to a function returning the string, but I am still wondering where the error is here.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare it in your header file as

extern char error[];

and in your code file (.c file) , declare it

char error[1024];

You are allocating it twice

Comment: The second, without extern, is a definition.

Comment: Tried that and the library cannot recognize the array.
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _HError

Comment: You may have special issues with your DLL file, as you hint in your question that is what you're targetting.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use function like this:

in .h:

```
char* GetErr();
```

and in .cpp:

```
char* GetErr() { return error; }
```

Try to avoid global variables. In file scope its pretty safe, but if you try to use it trough many files it can cause big errors.

Comment: What's wrong with a global array? How will having a "get" function prevent 'big errors' if many files use it? They still have access to the array.

Comment: They have if they explicitly declare to use it. You avoid for example names errors while `error` is rather popular name for variable:P Hiding implementation is always a good practice.

Comment: That's what I did in order not to get stuck. But I still would like to know how to define a global array...

Comment: Gray: The solution is to *declare* it in the header and *define* it in the implementation (.c) file, as Larry's answer almost says exactly.  Also see the declaration/definition examples at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037880/how-can-i-avoid-including-class-implementation-files/2038233#2038233