# Cyclic dependency between header files

Tags: c++, header, cyclic-dependency

I'm trying to implement a tree-like structure with two classes: `Tree` and `Node`. The problem is that from each class I want to call a function of the other class, so simple forward declarations are not enough.

Let's see an example:

**Tree.h:**

```
#ifndef TREE_20100118
#define TREE_20100118

#include <vector>
#include "Node.h"

class Tree
{
    int counter_;
    std::vector<Node> nodes_;

public:

    Tree() : counter_(0) {}

    void start() {
        for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
            Node node(this, i);
            this->nodes_.push_back(node);
        }
        nodes_[0].hi();    // calling a function of Node
    }

    void incCnt() {
        ++counter_;
    }

    void decCnt() {
        --counter_;
    }

};

#endif /* TREE_20100118 */
```

**Node.h:**

```
#ifndef NODE_20100118
#define NODE_20100118

#include <iostream>
//#include "Tree.h"

class Tree;    // compile error without this

class Node
{
    Tree * tree_;
    int id_;

public:

    Node(Tree * tree, int id) : tree_(tree), id_(id)
    {
//      tree_->incCnt();    // trying to call a function of Tree
    }

    ~Node() {
//      tree_->decCnt();    // problem here and in the constructor
    }

    void hi() {
        std::cout << "hi (" << id_ << ")" << endl;
    }

};

#endif /* NODE_20100118 */
```

**Calling Tree:**

```
#include "Tree.h"
...
Tree t;
t.start();
```

This is just a simple example to illustrate the problem. So what I want is calling a function of `Tree` from a `Node` object.

**Update #1:** Thanks for the answers. I tried to solve the problem like in Java, i.e. using just one file per class. It seems I will have to start separating .cpp and .h files...

**Update #2:** Below, following the hints, I pasted the complete solution too. Thanks, problem solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the headers, forward declare the member functions:

```
class Node
{
    Tree * tree_;
    int id_;

public:
    Node(Tree * tree, int id);
    ~Node();
    void hi();
};
```

In a separate .cpp file that includes all the required headers, define them:

```
#include "Tree.h"
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node(Tree * tree, int id) : tree_(tree), id_(id)
{
  tree_->incCnt();
}

Node::~Node() 
{
  tree_->decCnt();
}

etc
```

This also has the effect of keeping your headers readable, so it is easy to see a class's interface at a glance.

Answer (score 3):

Following the hints, here is the complete solution.

**Tree.h:**

```
#ifndef TREE_20100118
#define TREE_20100118

#include "Node.h"
#include <vector>

class Tree
{
    int counter_;
    std::vector<Node> nodes_;

public:

    Tree();
    void start();
    void incCnt();
    void decCnt();
};

#endif /* TREE_20100118 */
```

**Tree.cpp:**

```
#include "Tree.h"
#include "Node.h"

Tree::Tree() : counter_(0) {}

void Tree::start()
{
    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        Node node(this, i);
        this->nodes_.push_back(node);
    }
    nodes_[0].hi();    // calling a function of Node
}

void Tree::incCnt() {
    ++counter_;
}

void Tree::decCnt() {
    --counter_;
}
```

---

**Node.h:**

```
#ifndef NODE_20100118
#define NODE_20100118

class Tree;

class Node
{
    Tree * tree_;
    int id_;

public:

    Node(Tree * tree, int id);
    ~Node();
    void hi();
};

#endif /* NODE_20100118 */
```

**Node.cpp:**

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "Tree.h"

#include <iostream>

Node::Node(Tree * tree, int id) : tree_(tree), id_(id)
{
    tree_->incCnt();    // calling a function of Tree
}

Node::~Node() {
    tree_->decCnt();
}

void Node::hi() {
    std::cout << "hi (" << id_ << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `Tree` requires the definition of `Node` but not the other way around so your forward declaration is correct.

All that you have to do is removed the definition of any functions that require a full definition of `Tree` from the `Node` class body and implement them in a `.cpp` file where full definitions of both classes are in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Can you but the constructor/destructor bodies in a .cxx file? You could include Tree.h there.