# C++ header files including each other

Tags: c++, header

I have 2 files that are both including the other file and I am getting strange errors.

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include "model.h"
etc....
#endif

#ifndef MODEL_H
#define MODEL_H

#include "Node.h"
etc....
#endif
```

Here is my example code of what I am doing. Can somebody explain to me why this is not possible or allowed? And what I should do to get passed this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cyclic dependency between header files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089056/cyclic-dependency-between-header-files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a [*circular dependency*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) between `Node` and `model`.

To deal with this, instead of...

```
#include "Node.h"
```

...in model.h , forward declare...

```
class Node;
```

...and this will allow you to have `Node& node;` in your `Model` `class`.

Or vice-versa.

Better still... see if you can revisit your design and eliminate this circular dependency.