# Cyclic class dependency while including header files in C++

Tags: c++, class, header, include, dependencies

I'm developing a C++ program using visual studio 2010. I've these class definitions & header files :

s.h :

```
class s : oe {
    ...
};
```

t.h :

```
class t : oe {
    ...
};
```

oe.h :

```
class oe {
    ...
    o getO();//we reference to class 'o' in oe.h, so we must include o.h begore oe.h
};
```

& o.h :

```
class o {
    ...
    s getS();//we reference to class 's' in o.h, so we must include s.h begore o.h 
};
```

the problem is that we reference to class 'o' in `oe.h`, so we must include `o.h` before `oe.h`, & also we reference to class 's' in `o.h`, so we must include `s.h` before `o.h`, but we can't do this because `s.h` needs `oe.h` & `oe.h` needs `o.h` & `o.h` needs `s.h` !

As you see, some kind of loop exists in class dependency cycle & so I can't compile the project. If i remove dependency between s.h & t.h & oe.h, the problem will solve (here is `stdafx.h` for this state) :

```
#include "s.h"
#include "t.h"
#include "o.h"
#include "oe.h"
```

but I have to use all given dependencies & I can't remove anyone of dependencies. any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cyclic dependency between header files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089056/cyclic-dependency-between-header-files)

Comment: Search for forwad declare and cyclic header dependency. There are tons of questions about that on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this using **forward declarations** instead and moving implementations to implementation files.

Instead of including a header for `s`, just forward declare it:

```
class s;
```

and you can use it as an incomplete type for just about anything except a data member of the class. (provided the implementations are separated).

**This, most probably, doesn't tackle the underlying problem**, which is your design.

Comment: I'd add +1 for the last line if I could!

Answer (score 0):

Forward declarations will work not only for pointers/references by for return values as well.

So, you can do something like this:

**oe.h:**

```
class o;

class oe {
    o getO();
};
```

**oe.cpp:**

```
#include "oe.h"
#include "o.h"

o oe::getO() {
    return o();
}
```

Rinse and repeat as necessary... Since you no longer have `#include`s in the `.h` files, there is no opportunity for circular include dependencies.

Comment: you should also add 'public:' keyword