# How to fix this class template error?

Tags: c++, class, templates, methods

This is my first time ever attempting to use class templates (I'm very new to C++)

I'm trying to create a very simple `Number` class.  To start, I'm creating a `ToString` method.  As of now, for testing purposes, I just want `ToString` to return the string `"testing"`.

When I run my code, I get the following error:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Number<int>::ToString()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [build/ml] Error 1`

Here is my code, any help is appreciated:

main.cpp

```
#include "number.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Number<int> x(15);
    x.ToString();
    return 0;
}
```

number.h

```
#ifndef _NUMBER_
#define _NUMBER_

#include <iostream>

template <class T> 
class Number {
    private:
        T m_val;
    public:
        Number(T val) : m_val(val) {};
        std::string ToString();
};

#endif
```

number.cpp

```
#include "number.h"

template<class T> 
std::string Number<T>::ToString() {
    return std::string("testing");  
}
```

Comment: Unlike normal code, you have to put templates entirely in the header file. (That's a simplification, but the easiest solution)

Comment: Make `ToString` a const function. You don't need to surround the quote with `std::string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include `number.cpp` in `main.cpp` (as a temporary workaround), instead of include `number.h`. Or move the function definition of `ToString()` into `number.h`, and only use `number.h`.

See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/3309790)

Comment: Are you really advising the OP to include a .cpp file in another .cpp file?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686204/why-should-i-not-include-cpp-files-and-instead-use-a-header

Comment: I ended up just moving the function definition of ToString into number.h