# How to include and compile multiple C++ files?

Tags: c++, compilation, include

I have these files: `classA.cpp`, `classA.h`, `classB.cpp`, `classB.h`, and `main.cpp`.
All needed libraries are included in both .h files.

In `main.cpp` I include `classA.cpp` and `classB.cpp`.
In `classB.cpp` I include `classB.h` and in `classA.cpp` it is `classA.h`

I compile it by

> g++ main.cpp

(+some unimportant stuff) and it is working perfectly.

But I am almost certainly sure, that on our lectures we were told to do that differently, sadly I can't find it now.
Is this the best way of **including** and **compiling**? If not, what is?

Comment: Why are you including cpp files from other cpp files? You've created one gigantic translation unit. Which C++ book are you using? This is all explained inside it.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I have no book, I am studying at university, sadly we only touched this topic yet.

Comment: @TGar You can always learn things outside of class. The Internet has many many resources.

Comment: So I should include only .h files? It will now where to find the rest? Sorry until now I always have all my programs in single file.

Comment: _"I have no book"_ There's your problem then. No book, no lecture notes... how do you expect to learn without a learning resource!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I didn't have problem until now, I use cppreference.com.

Comment: You can't learn the language from a reference. Here are some books: http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648 "How to include" is too broad for an SO Q&A. Good luck!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1686204/560648 actually may be useful

Comment: Include the header files instead of cpp files, then do: `g++ main.cpp classA.cpp classA.h classB.cpp classB.h` [see this doc](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/4708/compiling-and-building#t=201705081359124744663) for more details

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686204/why-should-i-not-include-cpp-files-and-instead-use-a-header

Comment: Questions asking for "the best way" tend to be viewed as being "primarily opinion-based".  What's best in one situation is not necessarily best anywhere else!

Answer (score 2):

the simply way:`g++ main.cpp ClassA.cpp ClassB.cpp etc.cpp`
more advanced way you should use a makefile.
[enter link description here](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/compilation.html)

Comment: You should probably also mention to include the headers in main.cpp not the cpp files..

Comment: I would say it really isn't the answer as it doesnt "answer" your question which was `Is this the best way of including and compiling? If not, what is?`  This doesn't explain at all anything about including.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you don't **include** source files into other source files.  In fact, the reason we have header files is so that we can use the same *declarations* in all files, whilst compiling *definitions* only once.

So your `main.cpp` should include `classA.h` and `classB.h` instead of `classA.cpp` and `classB.cpp`:

```
#include "classA.h"
#include "classB.h"

#include <algorithm> // and whatever else you need

int main()
{
    // your code....
}
```

Then write a simple Makefile:

```make
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra

main: main.o classA.o classB.o
    $(LINK.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^

main.o: main.cpp
main.o: classA.h
main.o: classB.h

classA.o: classA.cpp classA.h

classB.o: classB.cpp classB.h
```

For bigger projects, you can write a rule to create the dependencies from the source files automatically, but we can start as above by hand-generating them.

Now, the correct commands will be run when you execute

```sh
make
```