# C++ #include causing 'duplicate symbols'

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm starting a C++ OpenGL project, and I'm beginning with two .cpp files, `Scene` and `boilerplate` (with no .h files!). `boilerplate` contains OpenGL procedures that simply setup the environment.

I thought I'd move them to this separate file to give myself more room in `Scene`, but now that I've done so and attempted to `#include` this file in `Scene`, I'm getting 'duplicate symbol' errors when linking, e.g.

```
Scanning dependencies of target Coursework
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Coursework.dir/Scene.cpp.o
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable Coursework
duplicate symbol __Z12checkGLErrorv in:
    CMakeFiles/Coursework.dir/Scene.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Coursework.dir/boilerplate.cpp.o
duplicate symbol __Z5setupv in:
    CMakeFiles/Coursework.dir/Scene.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Coursework.dir/boilerplate.cpp.o
duplicate symbol _height in:
    CMakeFiles/Coursework.dir/Scene.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Coursework.dir/boilerplate.cpp.o
...
```

Every 'duplicate symbol' comes from the definitions in `boilerplate.cpp`.

Why am I getting these errors? I thought `#include`ing is effectively the same as copy-and-pasting that file's code into the current file, yet when I actually do this it builds just fine.

I'm using CMake to build, in case this is relevant (it is a linking error so it could be to do with this?).

---

Here are the files for reference,

Scene.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glut/glut.h>

#include "boilerplate.cpp"

void draw() {

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // make beautiful models

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    glutInit(&argc, argv);         
    setup();                        

    glutDisplayFunc(draw);          

    checkGLError();                 
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();                 

    return 0;
}
```

boilerplate.cpp:

```
#include <glut/glut.h>
#include <cstdio>

int width, height;

void checkGLError() {

    int e = 0;
    GLenum error = glGetError();

    while (GL_NO_ERROR != error) {
        e++;
        printf("GL Error %i: %s\n", e, gluErrorString(error));
        error = glGetError(); 
    }
}

void setup() {

    width = 800;                                    
    height = 800;                                   

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);  
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);           
    glutCreateWindow("Coursework");                 
}

void reshape(int _width, int _height) {

    height = _height;
    width = _width;

    GLdouble aspect = static_cast<GLdouble>(width) / static_cast<GLdouble>(height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();  
    gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 1, 1000);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);  
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(Coursework)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

# Put directories in project's 'include path'
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Declare the var 'SOURCE_FILES', and give it all relevant source filenames
set(SOURCE_FILES Scene.cpp boilerplate.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: Don't `#include` a .cpp file! You need to make a header file with just the declarations for `boilerplate.cpp`.

Comment: Do **not** include `.cpp` files in other files

Comment: I thought there was no real difference between .h and .cpp files though,  and that it was just 'good practice' to separate interface from implementation?

Comment: This question, though closed, might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/333889/10077

Comment: Of course there's no difference between files. One file is no different than any other file. It's just that what's inside the file that matters. If you include something that defines a symbol, that symbol gets defined by every file that includes. Hence, the duplicate symbols. `.h` files contains only declarations, and not complete definitions. It's not the difference between the filename extensions, it's their content that matters.

Comment: This one too is pretty similar to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49741617/c-include-causing-duplicate-symbols

Comment: @jhh: That *IS* this one!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't have a corresponding ```.h``` file for ```boilerplate.cpp```, so to fix this I should make one, that just contains just the declarations of ```boilerplate.cpp```'s procedures, then ```#include``` this instead?

Comment: @EdwardGargan I suggest you get good C++ reading material, and not try to learn C++ by winging it or lifting snippets of code from a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right when you say that `#include`-ing is just like copy-pasting the contents at the respective position.

But if you include a file that does not just contain declarations and class definitions but also implementations in the sense of variable definitions or function/methods with a body, then you might get into troubles if...

a.) you either include the same `boilerplate.cpp` in several other files; this will lead to redefining the same things -> duplicate symbol errors

b.) you include the `boilerplate.cpp` only in one file, but the compiler treats the `boilerplate.cpp` file also as separate translation unit -> duplicate symbols

So avoid including .cpp-files; rather expose the functions provided by that .cpp file as function prototypes (i.e. functions without a body) in an appropriate .h-file; include only the .h-files then.

Comment: For some reason, removing ```boilerplate.cpp``` from the list of source files CMake can see has fixed this issue. Have I just dug myself into a horrible program design?

Comment: Probably yes :-) Removing the file from the source file list accords to situation (b) mentioned in the answer; If it is a boilerplate, I assume that there is no "boilerplate.h" provided; in this case you should copy/paste the relevant portions of the boilerplate code into one of your "own" source files rather than including a "boilerplate.cpp"...

Comment: But if I'm _sure_ that I will only include this boilerplate once, ```#include```ing it here is technically OK to do? And yep there is no ```.h``` file, just the ```.cpp```.

Comment: It's technically correct; It is just a bit "unusual" and might therefore confuse readers or your code...

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was looking to use `#include` simply as a copy-and-paste tool, yet I was giving CMake `boilerplate.cpp` as a separate executable file, and attempting to both link it *and* `#include` it in `Scene.cpp` caused these duplicate symbol errors.

Removing `boilerplate.cpp` from CMake, i.e. removing it from

```
set(SOURCE_FILES Scene.cpp boilerplate.cpp)
```

solved the problem and allowed me to build it.

But as the comments say, the 'proper' way to have done this would have been to give `boilerplate.cpp` a header file and include this instead. I couldn't understand why this is the preferred way until I read this:

[Why should I not include cpp files and instead use a header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686204/why-should-i-not-include-cpp-files-and-instead-use-a-header?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)