# My template Binary Search Tree class gives error "Node<T>: no appropriate default constructor available," how can this be fixed?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

When trying to run my codebase, I am having an error that says:

> 'Node': no appropriate default constructor available   BST

I have an idea that this could be caused by BST.h:

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

// using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Node {
    public:
        Node(T n) : data(n), rlink(nullptr), llink(nullptr) {}
        ~Node() {}
    private:
        T data;
        Node *rlink, *llink;

};

template <typename T>
class BST {
public:
    BST();
    void insert(T &p);
private:
    Node<T> * root; 
};

#endif
```

Or if not that then caused by this function which is part of BST.cpp:

```
template <typename T>
void BST<T>::insert(T &p) {
    if (root != nullptr) {

    }
    else {
        Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>;
        cout << "UPD" << endl;
    }
}
```

The **cout is there for test purposes**. I **am aware of the usage of namespace** **std;** that is just there for quick-testing-purposes. That's not my priority, but **this is**. **Please**:

- **Help me fix this very problem**
- May I get your assistance and guidance as an answer on how I can fix this problem? I'm not sure how to fix it!

My **intention** is to do something like this:

```
Node *newNode = new Node;
newNode->data = new Packet(p);
```

but in a template version. How can I achieve this? I used to have the error "No default constructor for Packet" but that was fixed w/an edition of this:

```
Node(T n) : data(n), rlink(nullptr), llink(nullptr) {}
```

in BST.h. It used to be:

```
Node() : rlink(nullptr), llink(nullptr) {}
```

But then it introduced this error.

**For reference purposes:**

*BST.cpp*

```
#include "BST.h"
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
BST<T>::BST() : root(nullptr) {}

template <typename T>
void BST<T>::insert(T &p) {
    if (root != nullptr) {

    }
    else {
        Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>;
        cout << "UPD" << endl;
    }
}
```

*Packet.h*

```
#ifndef PACKET_H
#define PACKET_H

#include <string>

// using namespace std;

class Packet {
public:
    Packet(int partId, string description, double price, int partCount) :
        partId(partId), description(description), price(price), partCount(partCount) {}
    int getPartId() const { return partId; }
    string getDescription() const { return description; }
    double getPrice() const { return price; }
    int getPartCount() const { return partCount; }
private:
    int partId;
    string description;
    double price;
    int partCount;
};

#endif
```

*Main.cpp*

```
// using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

#include "BST.h"
#include "BST.cpp"
#include "Packet.h"

int main()
{
    BST<Packet> test;
    Packet one(1, "testPacket", 1, 1);
    test.insert(one);
    system("Pause");
}
```

Note: Commented out namespace std; but if you want to run the program, just uncomment. I just did it for testing purposes...

Comment: Which constructor are you expecting to be invoked by the expression `new Node<T>`?

Comment: No default constructor for `Packet`.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is this: Node *newNode = new Node; newNode->data = new Packet(p);...but in a template version. How can I achieve this??? And yes, I used to have "No default constructor for Packet" but I fixed that by added the T parameter into the Node()...

Comment: [Rethink `#include "BST.cpp"``](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686204/why-should-i-not-include-cpp-files-and-instead-use-a-header)

Comment: I don't believe #include is the problem of this error. How can I get this working the way I want??? What can I do? I just need to get over this hurdle and then the program should start working. It's this that seems to throw the program off.

Comment: The proper way to reduce our attention on `using namespace std;` is to remove it.

Comment: I don't think that will fix my glaring problem. I've commented out using namespace std; though. Any idea on how to fix my problem that it won't even allow the program to execute?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to reduce OPs sample to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
  Node(T n) : data(n), rlink(nullptr), llink(nullptr) {}
  ~Node() {}

  T data;
  Node *rlink, *llink;
};

int main()
{
#if 1 // Enough to reproduce the issue:
  Node<int> node;
#else // but this would do as well
  Node<int> *pNode = new Node<int>;
#endif // 1
}
```

Output:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:15:13: error: no matching function for call to 'Node<int>::Node()'
   Node<int> node;
             ^~~~
main.cpp:5:3: note: candidate: 'Node<T>::Node(T) [with T = int]'
   Node(T n) : data(n), rlink(nullptr), llink(nullptr) {}
   ^~~~
main.cpp:5:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:4:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr Node<int>::Node(const Node<int>&)'
 struct Node {
        ^~~~
main.cpp:4:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/204fc3affa52b134)</kbd>

From `gcc`, it sounds a bit different. (Not sure which C++ compiler is used by OP.) However, `Node<int>::Node()` is just the default constructor which is missed.

The thing about default constructors is that:

1. Default constructors might be generated by compiler
2. **if** there isn't any reason preventing this, e.g. a custom defined constructor.

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
  //Node(T n) : data(n), rlink(nullptr), llink(nullptr) {}
  ~Node() {}

  T data;
  Node *rlink, *llink;
};

int main()
{
#if 1 // Enough to reproduce the issue:
  Node<int> node;
#else // but this would do as well
  Node<int> *pNode = new Node<int>;
#endif // 1
}
```

compiles fine. Now, the compiler made a default constructor by itself.

Too bad – it is somehow illformed: `rlink` and `llink` are left uninitialized!

Just adding a read access to `node.rlink` or `node.llink` makes this obvious:

```
  Node<int> node;
  std::cout << "node.rlink: " << node.rlink << '\n';
  std::cout << "node.rlink: " << node.llink << '\n';
```

Warnings:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:16:39: warning: 'node.Node<int>::rlink' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   std::cout << "node.rlink: " << node.rlink << '\n';
                                  ~~~~~^~~~~
main.cpp:17:39: warning: 'node.Node<int>::llink' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   std::cout << "node.rlink: " << node.llink << '\n';
                                  ~~~~~^~~~~
```

Output:

```
node.rlink: 0x4007d0
node.rlink: 0x7ffdd1e7e250
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07db7f3270b8c91d)</kbd>

I must admit I'm quite sure that reading unitialized members is [U.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior/4105123#4105123).

To summarize:

1. A default constructor is generated only if there are no user provided constructors.
2. A generated default constructor relies on that every class member is default constructable.
3. A generated default constructor might be a bad choice (e.g. for [POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure) member types like raw pointers).

There are two possible fixes:

First: Define a default constructor (additional to the already existing):

```
  Node(): data(), rlink(nullptr), llink(nullptr) {}
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b37e9d22e4989a1a)</kbd>

Second: Modify the constructor that it can be used as default constructor by applying default values to arguments:

```
  Node(T n = T()) : data(n), rlink(nullptr), llink(nullptr) {}
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87feb577d06ddf9c)</kbd>

---

Recommended reading: [**Default constructors** on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)

IMHO, worth to be mentioned: [**Rule of three**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

(I would recommend to delete default copy constructor and assignment in template `class Node`.)