# Issue of 'Uncaught TypeError: Callback must be a function' using C++ in Atom editor

Tags: c++, atom-editor

I'm using Atom to compile and run C++ code on Mac, however I'm getting this error on simple program. I am new to C++. Please help!

[image: Error in Atom]
Note: I was able to run this in Xcode.

main.cpp file:

```
#include "Cube.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  Cube c;

  c.setLength(3.48);
  double volume = c.getVolume();
  std::cout << "Volume: " << volume << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Cube.h file:

```
#pragma once
class Cube {
  public:
    double getVolume();
    double getSurfaceArea();
    void setLength(double length);

  private:
    double length_;
};
```

Cube.cpp file:

```
#include "Cube.h"

double Cube::getVolume() {
  return length_ * length_ * length_;
}

double Cube::getSurfaceArea() {
  return 6 * length_ * length_;
}

void Cube::setLength(double length) {
  length_ = length;
}
```

Comment: It seems you build the `main.cpp` source file as a separate program, without the `cube.cpp` source file or any object file created from it. You should do some research on the `make` program and how to write *makefiles* to build and link multi-file projects.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please don't post images of text. Images are impossible top copy-paste from, impossible to search for text in, and impossible for screen-readers to handle (and please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Thanks. And sorry about the poor question, I will edit into text.

Comment: @moe92 So the problem is as already stated. The reason you get the `undefined symbols` error is that you haven't told your compiler to compile Cube.cpp.

Comment: The `uncaught type error` seems to be a compiler/plugin bug. As you can see 'it has already been reported' so I think you are just going to have to live with it.

Comment: @john I got it! I needed to add "include Cube.cpp" in my main. Thanks!!

Comment: No! Do not include cpp files! You are supposed to compile each .cpp file separately and link them together. Figure out how to configure Atom to do so instead.

Comment: Ummm....okay, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Botje why am I not supposed to #include Cube.cpp in main.cpp? Isn't that how you would link files in C++?

Comment: No, you are supposed to compile each .cpp file separately into an object file (typically .o on Linux/macOS or .obj on Windows) and link the object files together into a program or (static) library. See [Why should I not include cpp files and instead use a header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686204/why-should-i-not-include-cpp-files-and-instead-use-a-header)

Comment: @Botje Got it! That was an excellent explanation as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a real build system. Atom-gpp is only suitable for single .cpp files.

I suggest you invest some time into CMake, which is a modern build system (primarily) for C and C++.

Given your project, put the following in `CMakeLists.txt` next to your .cpp files:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(course1)
add_executable(course1 main.cpp Cube.cpp)
```

These three lines are enough to tell CMake that you want to generate a program `course1` comprised of two .cpp files. CMake is clever enough to only compile files that you actually changed between runs.

Then you can either install a plugin like [AtomBuild](https://atombuild.github.io/) that will detect the CMake file for you and add the necessary integrations for building and running.

OR invoke CMake from the terminal:

```
$ cmake . # generates the build files
$ cmake --build . # actually builds
```

Note: you may need to install CMake first, on macOS the canonical installation method is using the Homebrew package manager:

```
$ brew install cmake
```

Comment: Can I follow up with you on this once I install CMake through Homebrew?