# vUsing a object of a type created in main.cpp in a different .cpp file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a vector of `Node` nodes which was created in main. The class `Node` is also contained in main.cpp. I have a separate .cpp and .h file for my DFS search function (my professor requested it be structured like this). The return type for my function is going to be a `vector<Node>`, but the compiler can't figure out what `Node` is. What can I do to use Node in my DFS search function? I played around with the extern keyword, but couldn't get it to help me. For clarity, here is some sample code:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "DFS.h"
//other include statements
using namespace std; 

 Node::Node(int id, vector<float> vec){
        this->nodeID = id;
        this->posVals = vec;  
    }
    
int Node::getNodeID(){
        return nodeID;
   }


int main(){
    vector<Node> nodeContainer;
    nodeContainer = load(); //load function reads in a file and dynamically creates nodes and
                            //pushes them to a vector that is returned to main
                 
    cout << "\n\n\n Adjacency List: \n" << endl; //I make an adjacency list of all the data
    AdjList adjList(nodeContainer);
    adjList.makeAdjList();
   

    dfsISearch(srcNode, destinationNode);  //function from DFS
}
```

**DFS.cpp**

```
vector<Node> dfsISearch(int src, int dest){
        vector<Node> vectorPath;
        return vectorPath;
    }
```

**DFS.h**

```
#ifndef DFS_H
#define DFS_H
#include <vector>
#include "Node.h"

    vector<Node> dfsISearch(int src, int dest);

#endif
```

**Node.h**

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

    class Node{
private:
public:
    int nodeID;
    vector<float> posVals;
    vector<int> connections;
    vector<pair<int, float> > destNodeWeightPair;

    Node(int id, vector<float> vec);
    
    int getNodeID();

    void addConnection(int connection);

    vector<int> getConnectionsVector();

    void addWeight(pair<int, float> pair);

    bool isConnection(int destNode);

    void display();
};

#endif
```

To solve, I moved added a Node.h header file, but now when I try to compile main.cpp I get this error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"dfsISearch(int, int)", referenced from:
_main in main-1e3844.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You need to put the definition of `class Node` in DFS.h.

Comment: how would I go about doing that? `class Node{ // all function and member variables};` because I just did that and it says "redefinition of Node in main.cpp, previous definition in DFS.h" is that correct, and I just have to take the definition out of main now?

Comment: Yes, if you **move** the declaration of `Node` into `DFS.h` file, you would have to remove that declaration from `main.cpp` and replace it with an `#include "DFS.h"` statement.

Comment: Now that I have done that, I'm getting this error when i try to compile main.cpp:         Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "dfsISearch(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-d87357.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: why do you still have a definition in main.cpp?

Comment: what is the definition you are referring to? If you mean the Node::Node functions, then I put them there because I have no where else to put them

Comment: @CrashMan123 what do you mean no where else to put them? put them in the classdefinition.cpp !

Comment: @CrashMan123 I don't mind if you send me your full code on my email-ID, I will check all the files and tell you the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Header files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/header-files-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Your main function shouldn't hold the functions/classes but merely control them. The right way is to declare it in a header file and then `#include "headerfile.h"` in any other place you would like to use them.

Example:

### Good practice

headerfile.h

```
#pragma once

class Entity
{
private:
    int num;

public:
    std::string name;
    void set_num(int);
};

extern int a;

int add(int,int);
```

headerfile.cpp

```cpp
#include "headerfile.h"

void Entity::set_num(int n)
{
    num = n;
}

int a = 5; // Definition of a

int add(int a,int b)   // Definition of add(int,int)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "headerfile.h" // Note: do no include the cpp file, but the .h file


int main()
{
    Entity e;
    std::cout << a;
    std::cout << add(5,10);
    return 0;
}
```

It is not extremely straightforward, you can read more about it [here](http://www.math.uaa.alaska.edu/%7Eafkjm/csce211/handouts/SeparateCompilation.pdf)

### bad practice

file.cpp

```cpp
class Entity{
private:
    int num;

public:
    std::string name;
    void set_num(int n)
    {
        num = n;
    }
};

int a = 5;

int add(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

and then the same but this time you `#include "file.cpp"`

**Don't use this method**. Even though it works it is a really bad way to achieve want you want to.

**[Why it is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686204/why-should-i-not-include-cpp-files-and-instead-use-a-header#:%7E:text=If%20you%20%23include%20a%20cpp,implementations%20of%20the%20same%20methods.)**

Comment: why is the bad practice way a bad way? Is it because all that logic is included again, when all you really need is the definition of the functions and variables?

Comment: @CrashMan123 [huge thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686204/why-should-i-not-include-cpp-files-and-instead-use-a-header#:~:text=If%20you%20%23include%20a%20cpp,implementations%20of%20the%20same%20methods.) also, if you found my answer helpful i'd appreciate if you would upvote it

Comment: Well i havent solved my problem just yet, I made a headerfile for the `Node` class in main, and I included it in main and in DFS.cpp and DFS.h (because Node is in a function definition) but now I am getting this error when I try to compile main.cpp:  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "dfsISearch(int, int)", referenced from: _main in main-d87357.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @CrashMan123 you need **no definition in main**, only declare it in the header file, and then define it in the cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate file (i.e Node.hpp) with your Node class, then include it in any other file you need.