# How to implement functions with template in .cpp file when declared in .h file

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'm learning c++ and I'm working with templates. When I declare  function in a header file with template, and implement it in cpp, it keeps saying `"undefined reference to void do_something<SomeEnum>()"`

.h file:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    Yes,
    No,
    Maybe
};


template<SomeEnum someEnum>
void do_something();
void do_something();
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "test.h"
#include "stdio.h"


template<SomeEnum someEnum>
void do_something() {
    printf("%d\n", someEnum);
}


void do_something() {
    printf("...\n");
}
```

main file:

```
...main function
do_something(); // no error
do_something<Yes>(); // thrown an error
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, templated functions are *defined* in the header file as well, although if you are adamant about keeping the declaration and definition separate, you can `#include ".cpp"` after your templated declaration in the header file. (See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) for more).

Comment: See also [Why should I not include cpp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686204/why-should-i-not-include-cpp-files-and-instead-use-a-header).

Comment: @rustyx -- that link involves a different issue. It's about `#include`ing source files in order to avoid linking. The `.cpp` files here are template definitions, which more typically use extensions like `.ipp`.

Answer (score 1):

### I use this format for such codes

> **Memory.hpp**

```
#ifndef __MEMORY_HPP__
#define __MEMORY_HPP__
    
    class Memory
    {
        public:

        Memory();

        template <uint8_t y, uint8_t x>
        void getMem(uint8_t (&data)[y][x]);

        template <uint8_t y, uint8_t x>
        void setMem(uint8_t (&data)[y][x]);
    };

#define __MEMORY_CPP__
#include "Memory.cpp"
#undef  __MEMORY_CPP__
#endif
```

> **Memory.cpp**

```
#ifndef __MEMORY_CPP__
#include "Memory.hpp"

    Memory::Memory()
    {
    }

#else

    template <uint8_t y, uint8_t x>
    void Memory::getMem(uint8_t (&data)[y][x])
    {
    }

    template <uint8_t y, uint8_t x>
    void Memory::setMem(uint8_t (&data)[y][x])
    {
    }

#endif
```

[cpp.template](/questions/tagged/cpp.template) [c++.template](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b.template) [seperate.template](/questions/tagged/seperate.template)