# Can only compile and run when including .cpp file

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, include

I'm doing some linked list practices in C++ and created a simple class for the single linked list. When I try to include the header-file in the main program however I get an undefined reference error. If I include the .cpp file however it works as I want it to.

It's been a while since I last coded in C++ and I can't for the love of me figure out what's wrong. Some help would be deeply appreciated. I'm using Windows Termnial with git-bash interface and g++ -std=c++11. The code is included below!

```
//The main file .cpp
#include "SingleNode.h"

int main() {
        SingleNode* tail = new SingleNode(2);
        SingleNode* head = new SingleNode(1, tail);
        head->print();
        return 0;
}
```

```
//SingleNode.h
#ifndef SINGLENODE_H
#define SINGLENODE_H

        class SingleNode {
                public:
                        int val;
                        SingleNode* next;
                        SingleNode();
                        SingleNode(int x);
                        SingleNode(int x, SingleNode* next);

                        void print();
        };
#endif
```

```
//SingleNode.cpp
#include "SingleNode.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
        SingleNode::SingleNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
        SingleNode::SingleNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
        SingleNode::SingleNode(int x, SingleNode* next) : val(x), next(next) {}

        void SingleNode::print() {
                if (this->next != nullptr) {
                        cout<<this->val<<"->";
                        this->next->print();
                } else {
                        cout<<this->val<<"->"<<"null"<<endl;
                }
        }
```

When run:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 LinkedList.cpp -o LinkedList.exe
C:\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEbmcRt.o:LinkedList.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `SingleNode::SingleNode(int)'
C:\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEbmcRt.o:LinkedList.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `SingleNode::SingleNode(int, SingleNode*)'
C:\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEbmcRt.o:LinkedList.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `SingleNode::print()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I instead `#include "SingleNode.cpp"` it works fine.

Comment: Fyi, [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Thank you! Looks like just a kind of read I needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You include the header file, so prototypes are available, and the compiler does not complain. The linker needs to find the source associated with those functions. Using `g++ -std=c++11 LinkedList.cpp -o LinkedList.exe` to compile means that you're only using the main file source and not the other file that contains the linked list implementation.

The solution is to also pass the `SingleNode.cpp` file to the compiler. Hence:

`g++ -std=c++11 LinkedList.cpp SingleNode.cpp -o LinkedList.exe` and include the `SingleNode.h` file in `LinkedList.cpp`.

The `#include` directive performs textual substitution, which means that when you include the `.cpp` file(which, in turn, includes the header file) you have one final [translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c) that contains the required source of both source files.

Also see: [Why should I not include cpp files and instead use a header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686204/why-should-i-not-include-cpp-files-and-instead-use-a-header)